# Creating/Parsing a dictionary of dictionary params

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am looking for help with some slightly more complex parameters than normal. The main motivation for this question is I am creating a node that must handle multiple pieces of hardware, and I must pass it unique parameters for each hardware. The number of hardware pieces is not defined and so I must be able to have any number of hardware/params (e.g. can't do left_camera and right_camera params).

I found that with rosparam I can create a list or dictionary parameter, and then parse it with roscpp. From my research I think I need to create a dictionary of dictionaries, but unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to properly create/parse such a parameter.

Inside my launchfile I have something that looks like:

```
    <rosparam param="hardware">
        hw1: { param1: value, param2: value }
        hw2: { param1: value, param2: value }
        hw3: { param1: value, param2: value }
    </rosparam>
```

Based on the example here http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam I can see how to create a XmlRpcValue type, but I'm still unclear on how to parse a more complex param. Any help is appreciated! Also feel free to tell me if this is the wrong way to handle this situation in ROS, I'd like to try to stick to ROS standards as much as possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197304/creating/parsing-a-dictionary-of-dictionary-params/) by [jsenna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20788/jsenna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Groovy and newer versions of ROS, roscpp has an API for retrieving a portion of the parameter tree as a std::map: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists

In python, retrieving a portion of the parameter tree is implicitly a dictionary.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsenna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20788/jsenna/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanks for the response, however I don't think that will work for me since it only seems to support lists or dictionaries of primitive types. I need to access a list of dictionaries (don't know what type that would even be, probably XmlRpcValue?)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-18**:
If you have nested dictionaries, you may need to parse by hand. I think a dict will have the `XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct` type, and you can use the `hasMember()` and `operator[] (std::string)` to retrieve the inner `XmlRpcValue`s from the map.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its standard yaml, so you can nest dictonaries and arrays inside of each other; If you have an unknown number of known instances (hardware configs), I guess an array of dictonaries is what you are looking for, e. g.:

```
<rosparam param="hardware">
    [ { name: 'hw1', param1: 1.3, param2: false }, { name: 'hw2', param1: 1.7, param2: true  }, { name: 'hw3', param1: -1.3, param2: true  } ]
</rosparam>
```

Now you can iterate the array and the read out the params of interest for each hardware....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsenna](https://answers.ros.org/users/20788/jsenna/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanks for the response, this does look like it will achieve what I want but I am still unsure about how to extract the parameters inside the list (examples I can find only deal with a list of primitives). Any chance you could provide a little code or pseudo-code snippet? Thanks